# Изменить количество записей на странице в LinkPager

Tags: php, yii2

Есть свой виджет `LinkPager`, который наследуется от `yii\widgets\LinkPager`.

```
namespace app\widgets\grid;

use yii\widgets\LinkPager as BaseLinkPager;

class LinkPager extends BaseLinkPager {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->pagination->pageSize = 2;
    }

    public function run() {
        return parent::run();
    }
}
```

Есть грид, который ссылается на него:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'summary' => '',
    'pager' => ['class' => 'app\widgets\grid\LinkPager']
]); ?>
```

в итоге при загрузке грида на первой странице выводится не 3 записи, как задано выше `$this->pagination->pageSize = 3;`, а 20, как это по умолчанию задано в `$pagination` в `yii\widgets\LinkPager`. Но, если в адресной строке дописать `GET` зараметры:
`?page=1&per-page=3` - все сработает.

Вопрос: что я должен прописать в `LinkPager`, чтобы сразу по дефолту ограничить количство выводимых записей? `$this->pagination->setPageSize(3);` и `$this->pagination->defaultPageSize` - тоже пробовал. Не отображает по три записи и всё тут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав везде где можно понял, что минимально можно описать в конфиге через DI

```
'container' => [
    'definitions' => [
        'yii\data\Pagination' => ['defaultPageSize' => 10,
    ],
]
```

Жалко это выглядит как костыль ибо в `LinkPager` можно задать абсолютно любые параметры пагинатора, а вот этот - нет.